# How to combine a Text and TextField for voice over-support but keep the textField trait

Tags: swift, swiftui, accessibility, voiceover

I'm having a custom `TextField` struct, where i'm using the `.accessibilityElement(children: .combine)` to make Siri read out both the `Text` + the `TextField` values, but "she" drops the textField accessibility trait for the textField, which reads how "Double tap to edit". And I can't really find a way how to readd except setting my own hint, which seems kind of bad. Is there any better solution for this problem?

```
struct CustomTextField<F: ParseableFormatStyle>: View where F.FormatOutput == String {
    let title: String
    var value: Binding<F.FormatInput?>
    let format: F

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 6) {
            Text(title)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            TextField("", value: value, format: format)
                .autocorrectionDisabled()
        }
        .accessibilityElement(children: .combine)
        //        .accessibilityHint("Double tap to edit") // Is this the only way?
    }
}
```